# PowerPoint does not save modified properties

Tags: c#, .net-core, powerpoint, interop

I am attempting to modify the Title and Author built-in properties of a PowerPoint presentation written in C# (using .Net Core 6, and the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint assembly v2.12). While the file is open I can write new values and read them back with no problem.
However, if I Save() then Close() the file, when I re-open it the properties have reverted.

I am using a function like this (non-core code omitted):

```
        protected static void SetNamedPropertyValue(string propertyName, string value, object props)
        {
            dynamic propsType = props.GetType();
            object prop = propsType.InvokeMember("Item", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, props, new object[] { propertyName });
            prop.GetType().InvokeMember("Value", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, prop, new object[] { value });
        }
```

where the props object passed in is the BuiltInDocumentProperties property of the COM object representing the Powerpoint Presentation. No errors are reported.

What must I do to make my changes persistent?

Comment: You may consider using NuGet package [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/). When using _DocumentFormat.OpenXml_ it's helpful to use the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5)